# In ggplot2, how can I make the plotted data transparent?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make the left picture like the right picture. The blue line is linear regression created by 'stat_smoot function".
I tried to find the function for doing that but it did not work.

[image]

And also, the below is data with the written code by me.
[code]

```
fbdata <- read.csv("congress-data.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

new_df <-fbdata %>% 
  group_by(screen_name)%>% 
  mutate(average_likes = mean(likes_count), average_haha = mean(haha_count))

new_df <- new_df[, -c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]

new_df

p_one <- ggplot(new_df, aes(x=average_likes, y=average_haha)) + stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = T, na.rm = T) + 
xlab("Average number of likes per post") + ylab("Average number of HAHA reactions") +
ggtitle("Senator Tommey, Congressman Duncan, and Congresswoman Waters are the funniest legislators on 
      Facebook") +
scale_x_log10(breaks =c(100, 10000)) + scale_y_log10(breaks = c(1,100)) +
theme_minimal() 

p_one


p_one <- p_one + geom_text(aes(label=screen_name, alpha = average_haha), fontface ="bold") +
theme(legend.position = "none")

p_one
```

[data sample]

```
       name                average_likes average_haha
                               <dbl>        <dbl>
1 RepEspaillat                  10.4       0.0652
2 CongressmanCulberson          10.3       0.0833
3 RepAndyBiggs                  74.1       2.59  
4 derek.kilmer                 171.        0.978 
5 CongressmanNadler             64.8       0.283 
6 repsaludcarbajal             247.        0.727 
7 RepBobbyScott                 70.7       0.455 
8 SenatorTomCotton             652.        4.26  
9 RepMarkDeSaulnier            106.        1.18  
10 RepDavidEPrice               232.        0.5
```

How can I do this? could you recommend some functions or advice?

Comment: `alpha` is the transparency parameter, ranging from 0 (completely transparent) to 1 (completely opaque). If you want your text transparent, put, e.g.,  `alpha = 0.3` in your `geom_text`  layer. Alternately, you can map it to a column inside `aes()` (just like color or anything else), to have the transparency value depend on data.

Comment: In one plot you set alpha, in the other you didn't. I don't get what the question is, since you set the plots up differently and thus get different things

Comment: Add `geom_smooth` after you add `geom_text`, otherwise the regression line will be behind the text.